# Issue installing google maps api in intellij

Tags: android

I have always been a user of IntelliJ since my highschool CS teacher introduced us to it and I wanted to try and make a basic Map Application for Android with it. However, I am having a lot of trouble actually installing the Google Maps API. I have looked and looked online and all I seem to find is outdated help that is no longer of any help. Google has eliminated their code.google.com developer website and released it as developer.google.com, in this process alot of the information that I have looked at for help has lead me in completely wrong directions. I have tried using the tutorial on the developer website but a lot of the steps are misleading and seem to be missing steps.

If anyone could help me out and point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post however far you got, even if it is hopelessly broken?

Comment: Yes sorry. Thought being a little bit more general might help, since I might have to start from the beginning. I have downloaded and installed the Google Play Services API from the SDK Manager. However, when I try and add the API to my current project, as in add the module via project structure, it never autoformats as it should and I get tons of errors and problems with it.

Comment: Here is the error that I get and once the google_play_services_lib shows up in the project window, even more errors come out.

http://gyazo.com/a5696a24541ece5377552fbc43e8e714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Save you some trouble and use Android Studio, which is based on intellij, but imho much more user friendly.
Dealing with dependencies and librairies such as Google play Services and Google Maps is such a pain in intellij.
Just use Gradle in Android Studio (natively installed, unlike in intellij).

To add any library, just locate your build.gradle file in your app folder, and add your libraires to "dependencies", e.g :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
}
```

2- Follow this guide : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Follow the Google Play Services installation carefully.

The tricky part is then the API key. If the map doesn't appear, but the map fragment shows "google" then you'll have an api key problem.

Comment: I had seen the Android Studio, didn't think anything of it because I have always used IntelliJ, guess this saves a step because it looks the EXACT same. Also, there are 2 build.gradle files. Shoud I used the "Project: Pacemaker" or the "Module: App"?

Comment: Nevermind I'm a derp. Also, when I get the API Key, as long as I just add it to the Manifest.xml file properly it should work correct?

Comment: I am wondering where your seing these two. When you create a project you should see two files "build.gradle", one in your root package directory, the other in your app directory. There's also a settings.gradle.

Comment: Yes, in my experience is doesn't happen instantly, but within minutes.

Comment: If you have some problems with the SHA1 & keystore, you can find the right SHA1 in the error logs of AS under : "Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):"